# Why are there two similar action buttons in Kendo UI Upload template?

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-template, kendo-upload

From the Kendo UI API reference: "To render an action button for each file, add the following markup to the template: `<button type='button' class='k-upload-action'></button><button type='button' class='k-upload-action'></button>`"

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/upload/configuration/template

Can someone explain, why there are two similar buttons in the markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the source code (which requires a license from Telerik), those buttons take different functions depending on the scenario:

1. retry
2. remove
3. pause
4. cancel

Pause and cancel can be available at the same time (if `async.chunkSize` is set), or retry and remove can both be visible in case of an error.